# angular form action post not working

Tags: angularjs, html, forms

I have written the below code in html but getting an error of "The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used."

in my html:

```
<form name="payment" action="{{vm.resource.authEndpoint+ '/Payment/SecondOpinionCasePayment'}}" method="post">
```

in html page source:

```
<form name="payment" action="" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
```

I do not understated that Why action is going black. what is alternate  for form post?

Getting below angular error.

Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bvm.resource…%252Fapi*****.azurewebsites.net%252FPayment%252FSecondOpinionCasePayment
    at Error (native)
    at http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:11:417
    at K (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:93:52)
    at http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:114:238
    at Object. (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:112:433)
    at l.$digest (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:128:3)
    at l.$apply (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:131:58)
    at l (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:86:171)
    at S (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:90:301)
    at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (http://*****.azurewebsites.net/lib.min.js:91:315)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form the URL in you controller wrapping it with `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()`
use `$sce` to sanitize elements from potentially insecure content, if you trust the URL you can use `$sce`.

Inject `'ngSanitize'` in your app,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

then controller would be,

```
app.controller('urlController',['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){

var actionURL = vm.resource.authEndpoint+"/Payment/SecondOpinionCasePayment";

    $scope.formAction = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(actionURL);

}]);
```

then in your html form,

```
<form name="payment" action="{{formAction}}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably have in the scope is the model for the base url.
modify it as:

```
<form name="payment" action="{{vm.resource.authEndpoint}}/Payment/SecondOpinionCasePayment" method="post">
```

Comment: I have updated code as per you comment but not working

Comment: not enough information to help you further, the error seems to be in vm.Resource, share the angular code.

Comment: in html
<div class="container m-t m-b" ng-controller="TakeOpinionCtrl as vm" ng-init="vm.checkCustomerLogin()">

in .js
 var vm = this;

Comment: I tired also print in div and work but it's not work in form post

<div>{{vm.resource.authEndpoint+'/Payment/SecondOpinionCasePayment'}}</div>